# Is it possible put in textbox text and 2 radio buttons in Kendo-UI?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo-UI and I have a question because i dont find a solution in a documentation.

I want to add in textbox Text and 2 radio buttons? How should i make this? Or is it possible to make this using kendo textbox or exist another way?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean? Radio buttons inside a textbox? I don't think that is possible. To me, your image looks like a radio group with a label and 2 radio buttons.

Comment: @SJaka Сan you provide a sample code of a radio group in Kendo, please?

Comment: The only replacement for standard radio buttons in KendoUI is is the buttongroup: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/buttongroup/index. If the radios represent 2 states, you could also use the switch: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/switch/index

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kendo for ASP.Net MVC, here is the link:

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/radiobutton/overview ,

I don't use Kendo-UI for jQuery, however, if you are, this might help: http://jsdev.wikidot.com/blog:5